# PN532 NFC module not working on Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, c, node.js, nfc

I am trying to discover why my Pi 3 is not able to communicate with PN532 NFC module.

I'm using a couple of libraries to do it (libnfc and NPM PN532), but it's not working.

I followed the steps of the folowing answer and other sites, but I still having problems.

link: [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3)

The only difference that I have to the answers I've consulted are in my file /boot/cmdline.txt:

**My:**

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0  console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

**Answers:**

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0  console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

Does anyone had this error in your new **Raspberry Pi 3**?
Thak's for your attention to my question.

**Note:**

Error in libnfc:

```
pn53x_check_communication: Success
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_uart    Unable to transmit data. (TX)
lt-nfc-poll: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device.
```

NPM PN532: Keeps idling in this message:

```
debug: [frame-emitter] listening to data
debug: [hsu] Initializing serial port...
debug: [hsu] Serial port initialized.
info: [pn532] Configuring secure access module (SAM)...
debug: [pn532] Sending buffer: <Buffer xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx>
debug: [hsu] Waking up PN532...
```

Comment: Can you share dmesg output while running your `nfc-poll` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to install NFC PN532

- The Raspberry pi 3 has changed things around a bit: ttyAMA0 now refers to the serial port that is connected to the bluetooth. The old serial port is now called ttyS0. So *if you have an RPI3*, everywhere you see *ttyAMA0* below, you should read *ttyS0*

  So:

  - The /dev/ttyAMA0 previously used to access the UART now connects to Bluetooth.
  - The miniUART is now available on /dev/ttyS0.

---

- There is one killer feature "Baudrate derived from system clock" which makes the miniUART useless as the this clock can change dynamically.
  ** Modifying the */boot/config.txt* removes this dependency by adding the following line at the end:

  ```
  core_freq=250
  ```

  This fixes the problem and appears to have little impact. The SPI clock frequency and ARM Timer are also dependent on the system clock.

---

- For some bizarre reason the default for Pi3 using the latest 4.4.9 kernel is to DISABLE UART. To enable it you need to change  *enable_uart=1* in */boot/config.txt*.

  This also fixes the core_freq so that's no longer necessary.

---

- The kernel will use the port as controlled by kernel command line contained in */boot/cmdline.txt*. The file will look something like this:

  ```
  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
  ```
- The console keyword outputs messages during boot, and the kgdboc keyword enables kernel debugging. You will need to remove all references to ttyAMA0. So, for the example above */boot/cmdline.txt*, should contain:

  ```
  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
  ```

---

- *Disable* console on UART

  ```
  raspi-config -> Advanced Options -> Serial
  ```

You must be root on PI to edit this (e.g. use sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt or sudo raspi-config). Be careful doing this, because a faulty command line can prevent the system booting.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say anything about the changes you have done according to the link you shared ([How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3)).

In Rassperry Pi 3, `/dev/ttyAMA0` points to the serial point connected to bluetooth. UART is moved to `/dev/ttyS0`.

I suggest you to

- rollback what you have already done, because those changes might have broken some standard configurations.
- disable console on UART (`raspi-config -> Advanced Options -> Serial`).
- set `enable_uart=1` in `/boot/config.txt`, because the previous step sets `enable_uart=0` which causes `/dev/ttyS0` to disappear.
- set `pn532_uart:/dev/ttyS0` instead `/dev/ttyAMA0` in `/etc/nfc/libnfc.conf`. `libnfc` may not be updated to know and work with the new serial port (`ttyS0`).

Comment: `set pn532_uart:/dev/ttyS0 instead /dev/ttyAMA0 in /etc/nfc/libnfc.conf. libnfc may not be updated to know and work with the new serial port (ttyS0).`

Comment: Doing this, it started again. Thanks for the great help.